# Subscribe to RSS feed in Mail app (iOS 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, mail.app, rss

In Lion's Mail app, I can subscribe to RSS feeds and have them show up in the inbox.  Can I do the same with the Mail app in iOS 5.1.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the iOS mail app does not double as an RSS reader. Fortunately, however, there are many great RSS apps in the app store, my personal favorite is Reeder ([iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/reeder/id325502379?mt=8), [iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/reeder-for-ipad/id375661689?mt=8)).

Comment: just curious, do you genuinely like using Mail.app as your RSS reader?

Comment: Yep.  Why run a separate app?  Mail's already open.

Comment: Fair enough. I run Sparrow (both on iOS and OSX) for mail and Reeder for RSS. I like single purpose software.